# How to calculate variance from covariance matrix in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, mean

I'm trying to calculate variance from covariance matrix and the proportions of each stocks.
Here's my code:

```
for num in range(9):

result_table2.iloc[num]['Expected Return'] = arith_mean.dot(result_table1.iloc[num])
for num in range(9):

result_table2.iloc[num]['Standard Deviation'] = (result_table1.iloc[num])@V.values
```

The first one worked and the second one failed
result_table1:
[image]
result_table2:
[image]
covariance matrix:
[image]

Comment: Please include the relevant code as text and example of input and desired output (maybe calculate a small case manually)

Comment: Maybe replace `std` by `var` in whatever you did in the last step... but is difficult to say without your actual code. See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Comment: @Caridorc Hi, I just added my code, hope it works better!

Comment: "How to calculate variance from covariance matrix in python?" This is `x'Cx` where x[i] are the amounts (or fractions) in instrument i and C is the covariance matrix.